# how to create a responsive scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm currently creating a 2D Android and iOS game using Unity3D engine. I'm testing the game on a nexus 5, and an iPhone 5s device. Everything until now is working fine and I am pretty happy with the result, but when I test that application on an iPad or a Samsung tablet all the objects in my game scene *are not in the correct position anymore*. Is this a common problem in Unity3D ?

I know I am missing something but I tried to do some research and what I found is only by *changing the orthographic camera scale might fix this problem*, but I found it as a big amount of code to write as my game have not only one scene but multiple scenes and every scene have it's own game objects.

Is there any other method to do, a good and simple work around for this problem?

Comment: Which version Unity3D you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about setting the Anchors right.
If you're using the new UI System, make sure you anchor the objects where you want them to be, that's how you will achieve resolution independence.

For more information about anchoring, see [this tutorial](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui/rect-transform)

Answer (score 1):

Don't have separate scenes for separate devices. You can use the Screen object to check the height and width of your display. Then you can use this to set the orthographic size of your camera to something that makes everything visible as expected.

Comment: can you provide an example or link me to some online examples ?

Answer (score 0):

Update: **I misunderstood your question, you say GameObject, i understand UI.**

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25160299/1631457). I don't have this issue on my game. But when i try it with mac or windows machines, it is problematic. So maybe this can solve.
Other solution is more common which is you and Agumander say, change `orthographic size` of `Camera`.

**This Is for UI**

You can use Unity UI, and don't need to seperate. There are so many different resolution and density devices, you need to create so many scenes. So it is meanless separating scenes.

Unity UI has pixel based solutions which can be very helpfull for many density and resolution options. Forexample, It has `VerticalLayoutGroup` and `HorizontalLayoutGroup` for easy list like element visulation.

Most important thing is: Do you want to change UI for different screen size or resolutions? For example iPad has larger screen so user can be see more content. This change UX. Maybe you need to consider this.

Comment: does the UI take the default size of the device ? 
ie: so if i make all the game object under a UI canvas there will be no problem you say ???

Comment: Small differences may be occur. But i made a game. It looks like same Galaxy Note Pro 2 and Galaxy S 5-3.

Comment: that small difference is the problem for me

Comment: so first i should put all my game object as children for the orthographic camera then  i have to make a switch case on the device resolution and set the camera size based on the resolution as shown in the link you game me ?